# When should I pass "T* const&" type of pointer ?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, pass-by-reference

I would pass `T*&` pointer, when I am intending to change the pointed value inside the function:

```
void foo(char *&p)
{
  p = (b == true)? new char[10] : 0;
}
```

But I am not able to get what is the use case for `T* const&` kind of pointer (since that pointer is not changeable)? I mean why should not I pass simply `T* const` ?

```
void foo(char* const &p);  // p is not changeable
void foo(char* const p);   // p is not changeable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would use a `T* const &` as a parameter if the value of the pointer object might be changed by something external to your function and you wanted to be able to observe changes to the value of the pointer object or if you wanted to store a reference or pointer to the pointer object for later reading.

A `T*` parameter (equivalent to `T* const` as a function parameter) just gives you a copy of the pointer object, a snapshot of its value when it was passed to your function.

```
void foo( char* const& ptr )
{
    char* p1 = ptr; // initial value
    global_fn();    // ptr might be changed
    char* p2 = ptr; // new value of ptr
}
```

vs

```
void foo2( char* ptr )
{
    char* p1 = ptr; // initial value
    global_fn();    // ptr can't be changed, it's local to this function
    char* p2 = ptr; // will be the same as p1
}
```

Technically, even the function itself might change the value of the pointer to which it is passed a reference.

E.g.

```
char* p;

std::ptrdiff_t foo( char* const& ptr )
{
    ++p;
    return p - ptr; // returns 0, would return 1 if the parameter was by value
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "Hello, world!";
    p = test;
    foo( p );
}
```

Comment: But if it's changed by something external, it has to be volatile, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, I'm not sure why you think that.

Comment: [`The volatile type qualifier declares an item whose value can legitimately be changed by something beyond the control of the program in which it appears, such as a concurrently executing thread.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/888bfst6.aspx)

Comment: @Mehrdad: The change to the pointer only has to be made through something other than the `const` reference parameter. Strictly, it doesn't even have to be external to the function and certainly doesn't have to be beyond the control of the program.

Comment: I'm confused. Your answer says "You would use a `T* const &` as a parameter if the value of the pointer object might be changed by something *external* to your function", which can **only** be done by another thread... so you need volatile, don't you? Otherwise the compiler can magically make your program invalid with optimizations.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Firstly, if it were done by another thread, `volatile` isn't the answer. `volatile` and multithreading should never be together in your mind! It's completely misnomer that `volatile` fixes anything. That out of the way, no, it doesn't have to be done by another thread. Going off of the code Charles has posted: `char* globalP = 0; void global_fn() { globalP = new char; } int main() { foo(globalP); }`. Observe that during the execution of `foo`, `ptr` will change because `globalP` will change.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What about the external function call example that I posted? That change is external to the function. Yes, my original assertion that it has to be external to the function isn't quite true; it's just the most common way that this might happen. Even w.r.t. a second thread, the pointer might change value even if it wasn't declared `volatile` but the compiler might generate code that ignored this possibility and adding `volatile` is not necessarily going to make the code safe.

Comment: @Charles, @GMan: Is it just me, or does the program break the strict aliasing rule? You're accessing the same variable using both its name and a pointer (reference, in this case) to it, and one of them modifies it...
@GMan: Volatile and multithreading don't go *together* in my mind, but there's definitely an intersection of use cases for them.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's just you :-) . The "strict aliasing rule" is derived from the fact that it is not legal to write to an object of one type through a pointer or reference to a different type (with some exceptions). There is nothing illegal about accessing an object through multiple pointers or references that do have the correct type.

Comment: @Charles: Oh d'oh, totally forgot that it has to be of a different type. Never mind then.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is realistically nil. const references are used to prevent copying of expensive-to-copy or, in generic code, uncopyable types, but since pointers are trivial, it's negligible and you may as well take by value.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler example would illustrate the point that Charles Bailey is making. Let's remove the issue of the pointer part of it, because for this question it is irrelevant. So your question basically becomes:

```
void foo(const int &p);  // p is not changeable
void foo(const int p);   // p is not changeable
```

Do you see more clearly how it works? Yes, the local variable "p" cannot be assigned to in both cases. And yes, neither piece of code will affect the variable in the calling scope. But in the former example `p` could be a reference to a variable (non-const) int that can be changed while the latter is an argument passed by value which could not be changed. (Actually the `const` in the second example has no effect on anything outside the function, so it is kind of superfluous. Same with the second example in the question.)